# Key/Value pair as variable in PHP

Tags: php, associative-array, key-value-store

I'm have parsed a csv file into a associative array which looks like this:

```
array(5) {
[0]=>  array(13) { 
            ["First Name"]=>string(7) "Name"
            ["Last Name"]=>string(14) "Last name"
            ["Login"]=>string(22) "name.lastname"
            ["Email"]=>string(27) "email"
…
```

I now want to write the value of each key into a variable with the name of the key, e.g.:

```
$FirstName = "Name";
$LastName = "Last name";
```

As I am relatively new to programming and php I am struggling with this and I hope that you can give me a hint

Edit: This is how I create the array:

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=';')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}

$a_csv = csv_to_array($file, ';');
```

Comment: Cut the middle man out, show how you create this array and create the scalar values there, or maybe a Assoc array may be more appropriate

Comment: Check out [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: @berend Ouch thats a horrible and potentially insecure suggestion. Anyway keys with spaces dont work so well with extract

Comment: As I assume you have more than one occurance in this array, you cannot put all of these values into a scalar value. They would just Overwrite each other, you would end up with only the value from the last occurance in `$lastname` You could do one at a time while you do something with it, but then you may as well leave everything in the array and process it occurance by occurance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by moving data into a scalar. Data is quite happy and usable in an Assoc array.

Answer (score 0):

If your array was like this

```
array(5) {
[0]=>  array(13) { 
            ["foo"]=>string(7) "fooValue"
            ["bar"]=>string(7) "barValue"
            ,,,
```

For creating variables dynamically, at first you should make a loop

```
    foreach ($first_arrays as $first_array)
    {
        foreach ($first_array as $key => $value) {
            $name = str_replace(" ","",$key);  //replace spaces
            ${$name} = $value;   //create PHP variable with your key
        }
    }

echo $foo; // will be fooValue
// here you have all variables that named by your array keys
```

Comment: I assume the array is more than one occurance, so you cannot do this as you will just get one variable called foo that contains the value from the LAST Occurance of the array

Comment: Yes, it has more than one occurance.

Comment: So this would not be any use

Comment: No, For all array keys, you'll have variables; such bar and ,,,

Comment: Test your code with `$arr = array (array ('First Name' => 'Fred','Last Name' => 'Blogs','Login' => 'fred.bloggs','Email' => 'fred@email.com',),
    array ('First Name' => 'Noddy','Last Name' => 'Holder','Login' => 'noddy.holder','Email' => 'noddy@email.com',));`

Comment: My answer works for a simple associative array, Not a multiplex array, for your question.. if your array is multiplex, the answer will be different

Comment: The question itself gives an example which is a multidimensional array.

Comment: Yes you are right, But it does not make the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution was to walk through the array with foreach and just call the keys and assign them:

```
foreach ($csv as $value){

    $FirstName = $value["First"];
    $LastName = $value["Last"];
...
}
```

I was obviously making things harder as they were. Thanks for the input anyway :)